# $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x}$ using L'Hopital

Tags: limits

I have to evaluate
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x}$$
using L'Hopital's rule.

Since $f(x)=\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x}$, then
$$\ln(f(x))=\ln\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x}$$
Hence,
$$\ln(f(x))=\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x}}$$

Using L'Hopital in the right side, I get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{x^2}{2x+1}\cdot\dfrac{-2x^2-2x}{x^4}}{-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2x^2+2x}{2x+1}=\infty$$

Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=e^{\infty}=\infty$$
But I know the answer is $0$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You've expressed $\ln f$ as the ratio of two functions of respective $x\to\infty$ limits $-\infty,\,0$, a case L'Hôpital's rule doesn't cover.

Comment: @J.G.I know there's a easier way, but I suppose to use L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate it.

Comment: you have made an error while taking logarithm

Comment: Hint: use the rule in the opposite direction viz.$$-\infty\stackrel{\ast}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(2x+1)\ln(2x+1)-4x\ln x+2x}{2\ln x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2x+1)-2\ln x}{1/x}$$($\stackrel{\ast}{=}$ is an exercise).

Comment: $(0+)^{+\infty}$ is not an indeterminate form. The limit is $0.$

Comment: Basically, L'Hopital only applies when the expression is an indeterminate form, and $\frac{-\infty}{0^+}$ is not an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use L'Hopital here as upper part tends to $-\infty$
and lower part tends to 0.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. In this case, we can use the role with some creativity. See e.g. my hint.

Comment: Hi, I just point out why he cant do that, and thanks for hint, I am still working.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed we can't apply l'Hospital but the big mistake is not perform a preliminary analysis for the limit.

Indeed, in this case the original limit is in the form $0^\infty$ which *is not* an indeterminate form, indeed

$$\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x}=e^{x\log\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right) } \to 0$$

indeed

$$x\to \infty,\;\log\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right) \to -\infty\implies x\log\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right) \to -\infty$$

Moreover, l'Hospital rule, in general, is not a good way to determine limits, in particular when applied as you did as a black box without any preliminary analysis for the given expression.

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x}$$
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\ln{\left(\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\right)}}$$
$$e^{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln{\left(\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\right)}}$$
$$e^{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln{\left(\dfrac{2x+1}{x^2}\right)}}$$
$$e^{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln{\left(\dfrac{2x+1}{x^2}\right)}}{x^{-1}}}$$
Try using L'Hopital's Rule here